# Using Formik and wrapping Material TextField causing blur on keypress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, onblur

I'm not sure what I changed to make my custom `TextField`s to start behaving this way but I'm wrapping Material-UI `TextField`s to use Formik validation. I've included a full code sandbox to fork and play with.

Currently, when I type (or click an up/down arrow in the case of a numeric field) the field "blurs" and I have to refocus every `keypress` to continue typing. The numeric field causes the number to drop in value instead of increase.

Here is my custom `TextField` wrapper:

```js
import React from "react";
import { FieldAttributes, useField } from "formik";
import {
  InputBaseComponentProps,
  TextField as MuiTextField
} from "@material-ui/core";

interface TextFieldProps {
  label: string;
  inline?: boolean;
  inputProps?: InputBaseComponentProps;
}

const TextField: React.FC<FieldAttributes<TextFieldProps>> = ({
  inline = false,
  ...props
}) => {
  const { type, label, placeholder, inputProps } = props;
  const [field, meta] = useField<TextFieldProps>(props);
  const errorText = meta.error && meta.touched ? meta.error : "";

  const Field = () => (
    <MuiTextField
      {...field}
      label={label}
      variant="outlined"
      margin="dense"
      type={type}
      placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : label}
      helperText={errorText}
      error={!!errorText}
      inputProps={inputProps}
    />
  );

  return inline ? (
    <Field />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Field />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextField;
```

Below is the code sandbox in case my sample code has nothing to do with what I'm doing wrong:

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-black-jw717

Comment: Can my answer help you? If no, please provide more details for us.

Comment: @MicFung, your answer worked perfectly! I just needed to set aside time today to address it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are hitting the recreation of `MuiTextField` every time you enter text or focus on field.

React will run all the codes again when re-rendering in functional component, so the `Field()` will create `MuiTextField` again.

To solve it, you can separate the `Field` and `TextField` into 2 components.

```
const Field: React.FC<FieldAttributes<TextFieldProps>> = (props) => {
  const { type, label, placeholder, inputProps } = props;
  const [field, meta] = useField<TextFieldProps>(props);
  const errorText = meta.error && meta.touched ? meta.error : "";

  return (
    <MuiTextField
      {...field}
      label={label}
      variant="outlined"
      margin="dense"
      type={type}
      placeholder={placeholder ? placeholder : label}
      helperText={errorText}
      error={!!errorText}
      inputProps={inputProps}
    />
  );
};

const TextField: React.FC<FieldAttributes<TextFieldProps>> = ({
  inline = false,
  ...props
}) => {
  return inline ? (
    <Field {...props} />
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Field {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-rain-8tl14?file=/src/components/TextField.tsx:839-848

Comment: find a article for you to read: https://randyperez.tech/blog/nested-functional-components

Comment: I had a feeling adding the `Field` code was going to cause a problem. I've done this before and got similar behaviors.